# R calculation in a dataframe with a control or baseline group

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, rank, percentile

I have a dataframe df which containts estimates from 2 site (A&B), 2 groups (group1&2) with 3 different methods(method1, method2, method0):

```
df1<-data.frame(site=rep("A", 21),
               group=rep("group1", 21),
               estimate=c(rnorm(10, 15, 3), rnorm(10, 2, 7), rnorm(1, 6, 2)),
               method=c(rep(c("method1","method2"),each=10),"method0"))

df2<-data.frame(site=rep("B", 21),
                group=rep("group2", 21),
                estimate=c(rnorm(10, 13, 3), rnorm(10, 5, 7), rnorm(1, 9, 2)),
                method=c(rep(c("method1","method2"),each=10),"method0"))
df<-rbind(df1, df2)
df
   site  group    estimate  method
1     A group1  15.1561073 method1
2     A group1  14.4067422 method1
3     A group1  12.7428921 method1
..........

41    B group2   0.3548033 method2
42    B group2  10.5820482 method0
```

I would like to use method0 as a baseline group and calculate the relative percentage bias (rb) for each estimate at each site/group.

```
#for each site and group of estimate
rb<-(estimate-estimate0)/estimate0*100% 

# where estimate0 is the estimate of method0 of that certain site/group
```

and there is ONLY ONE estimate0 in each site/group. I was trying to write a simple function and use `apply` for each site/group, but didn't work out.

```
fun.rb<-function(df, basline){
  control<-df$method==baseline
  rb<-(df$estimate-control$estimate)/(control$estimate)*100%
  return(rb)
}    
df %>% group_by(site,group) %>% mutate(rb=fun.rb, baseline="method0")
```

Any input and comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple and more elegant way of what you're trying to do.

First, simplify your function (if your'e going to be using it in a pipe, it doesn't need to take the entire df as an argument):

```
fun.rb <- function(estimate, baseline){
  (estimate-baseline)/(baseline)*100
}
```

Now, all you need to do is create the baseline column, and then call your function for each row, passing in the estimate and baseline columns to your function:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(site,group) %>% 
  mutate(baseline = estimate[method=="method0"], rb = fun.rb(estimate, baseline))
```

Comment: Wow, it looks great. Thanks for fixing my function.

Comment: I should point out that you don't really need the function and you can do the entire thing inline, by replacing the function call with the computation inside the function.

Comment: yes, of course. That will make the codes even neater. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant. I'm just a hack. But I think it does what you want.

```
> library(dplyr)
> newdf <- df %>% filter(method=="method0") %>%
+   rename(method0_value = estimate) %>% 
+   select(-method)
> head(newdf)
  site  group method0_value
1    A group1      2.529237
2    B group2      7.863411
```

This data set would contain all your baseline/control values. 
The next bit of code merges it back to your initial dataframe and creates the variable you want. You could then remove the method0_value if you wanted to. It is a nice check.

```
> finaldf <- left_join(df,newdf,by=c("site","group")) %>% 
+   mutate(rb= (estimate/method0_value)*100)
> head(finaldf)
  site  group  estimate  method method0_value       rb
1    A group1  8.928171 method1      2.529237 352.9986
2    A group1 11.171023 method1      2.529237 441.6757
3    A group1 10.790150 method1      2.529237 426.6169
4    A group1  8.990635 method1      2.529237 355.4683
5    A group1 14.813661 method1      2.529237 585.6969
6    A group1 14.518803 method1      2.529237 574.0390
```

I know there are ways of doing this that might be more efficient, but I'm still a noob.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's quite intuitive though and actually only takes two lines of codes. Plus it does not require writing a function which is great.